# Cant find the issue in this loop

Tags: c#

I have a form that the user inputs values that i save in an array but when the user wants to cancel i want the user to be asked a final time if the user wants to go ahead and cancel a reservation. If the user declines this final time i want the program to go back to the GUI and focus on the textbox with all the rows of reservations and not do the cancelation but i show u the code i have written and it asks the user if they are sure and if not it still deletes the reservation and then focus on the textbox. What is wrong in my code?

```
public void Cancelreservation()
{
    int index = lstReservations.SelectedIndex;
    bool checkedindex = m_seatMngr.CheckIndex(index);
    if (checkedindex)
    {

        if (!m_seatMngr.CancelSeat(index))
        {
            if (lstReservations.SelectedIndex == -1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You need to select a row.", "Error!",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation,
                MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
                lstReservations.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The seat is not reserved! No need to cancel 
                                  reservation.", "Important Query", 
                                  MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                lstReservations.Focus();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Continue to cancel the reservation?", 
                                "Important Query", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) 
                                == DialogResult.No)
            {
                lstReservations.Focus();                                
            }
            else
            {
                m_seatMngr.CancelSeat(index);
            }
        }
    }
```

m_seatMngr

```
         public bool CancelSeat(int index)
    {

        if (m_vacantList[index] == "Reserved") 
        {
            m_nameList[index] = " - ";
            m_priceList[index] = 0;
            m_vacantList[index] = "Vacant";
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;              
        }

    }
```

Comment: This method is called only once? Did you checked what's happening with breakpoints how do you step in your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `m_seatMngr.CancelSeat(index)` is the method that actually cancels the seat, you are calling the method twice.  The second `if` statement, half a dozen lines into your code, is this:

```
if (!m_seatMngr.CancelSeat(index))
```

... and it seems likely (given the above assumption) that this line will cancel the seat before you even display the MessageBox.

Comment: Ahh since m_sedatMngr is a public bool it still preforms the cancelation as it only checks if the index is within range and then deletes it..and after that returns the true. Thanks!!  Now i just have to fix it :D

Comment: You sir are a genius! :) Written a new method that checks the seat if it is reserved or not and returning a true or false and then executesd the main code perfectly.  Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: No problem!  Please be sure to accept an answer on each of your questions (not just this one) - it helps make the content on StackOverflow more useful. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!m_seatMngr.CancelSeat(index))
{
    // the rest of your code, which displays the messageboxes
}
```

This is always calling m_seatMngr.CancelSeat, before you've even displayed any messageboxes.

Comment: You are right! I have fixed it now, i guess i had gone blind as i been at this for half the day! :'(  Thanks for the help!!